# I want to print input value into method

Tags: java, treemap

I want to print "point" into "printMethod" method.Such as "Player name is 
Michael point was 2000 and player position 1" how can I do that? Is there any proper way to do that easily.I can do it by creating a new method but it is so scribbled.

```
      public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        int returnPosition = calculatePosition(2000);
        printmethod("Michael" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(900);
        printmethod("Mark"  , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(800);
        printmethod("Halk" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(700);
        printmethod("Albion" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(600);
        printmethod("Cristine" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(500);
        printmethod("Emma" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(400);
        printmethod("Prince" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(300);
        printmethod("Jason" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(200);
        printmethod("Tim" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(100);
        printmethod("Bob" , returnPosition);

        returnPosition = calculatePosition(50);
        printmethod("Jackson" , returnPosition);
    }
    public static void printMethod(String playerName, int position){
        System.out.println("Player name is "+playerName+  " Point was " +point+ " and player position " +position );
    }
    public static int calculatePosition(int position){
        if (position > 1000){
            return 1;
        }else if (position > 500 && position < 1000 ){
            return 2;
        }else if (position > 100 && position < 400){
            return 3;
        }else{
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass point in `printmethod()` after changing its prototype

Comment: I don't understand..I see calculations for position but where and how do you calculate 'Point'?

Comment: point was not used yet.point means my input data (2000,900,800 etc).I want to use point into "printMethod" method for output. @smoggers

Comment: what is the Type of `point` `Intetegr` or `Array` or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my question solution after a lot of thought and review your code.Thank you, everyone.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Practise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter player name: ");
    String playerName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter player score: ");
    int score = input.nextInt();
    int finalScore = calculateSection(score);
    displayM(playerName , finalScore , score);
}

public static void displayM(String playerName,int finalScore, int score) {
    System.out.println("Player name is " + playerName + " score was " + score+ " position is "+finalScore);
}

public static byte calculateSection(int score) {
    if (score >= 1000) {
        return 1;
    } else if (score >= 500 && score < 1000) {
        return 2;
    } else if (score >= 400 && score < 500) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do rather this way

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Map<String, Integer> playersList = new TreeMap<>();

        playersList.put( "Michael", 2000 );
        playersList.put( "Mark", 900 );
        playersList.put( "Halk", 800 );
        playersList.put( "Albion", 700 );
        playersList.put( "Cristine", 600 );
        playersList.put( "Emma", 500 );
        playersList.put( "Prince", 400 );
        playersList.put( "Jason", 300 );
        playersList.put( "Tim", 200 );
        playersList.put( "Bob", 100 );
        playersList.put( "Jackson", 50 );

        playersList.forEach( ( playerName, points ) -> {

            printMethod( playerName, points, calculatePosition( points ) );
        } );
    }

    public static void printMethod( String playerName, int point, int position ) {

        System.out.println( "Player name is " + playerName + " Point was " + point + " and player position " + position );
    }

    public static int calculatePosition( int points ) {

        int position = 4;

        if ( points > 1000 ) {
            position = 1;
        } else if ( points > 500 && points < 1000 ) {
            position = 2;
        } else if ( points > 100 && points < 400 ) {
            position = 3;
        }

        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer.Thanks a lot. @Ravi MCA